# Ways to access In App Review Alert "cancel" and "submit" buttons in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, rating

I am using the library react-native-rate to add support to in-app reviews on both IOS and Android, but there is an issue. The library seems to only support logic that tells the developers if the Review alert window was shown to the user, but NOT the "Cancel" or "Submit" buttons. I am wanting to add specific logic to what happens if a user hits "cancel" vs "Submit". Are there any workarounds? Below is the link to the library.

Link: https://github.com/KjellConnelly/react-native-rate#readme

Comment: On iOS this module wraps the store kit review request.  This view, *by design* does not provide any feedback on what action the user took. This is to prevent rewarding reviews.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Thank you.